# SQL to search string using wild card charcters

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching

In SQL, I am searching for the logic to arrive at below solution.

Suppose the string input is

```
This is the time
```

**Case 1**: when no input provided the query should return first letter of every word resulting in `"T I T T"`.

**Case 2**: Input is T, then it should show the next characters following.

Example: `"h h i"`

Any inputs on how the solution can be arrived?

Comment: with a case statment/decode combined with doing a substring

Comment: thanks Kevin. any example or pointer would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `REGEXP_REPLACE` for this. First add a blank in front of your string. Thus you always look for the character following a certain letter (e.g. the letters following 't' or the letters following blank).

```
select
  case when instr(t.text, c.chr) > 0 then 
    regexp_replace
    (
      t.text, 
      c.chr || '([^' || c.chr || '])[^' || c.chr || ']*', -- search pattern
     '\1 ', -- replace pattern
      1, 0, 'i' -- from the start, all occurerences, case insensitive
    )
  else
    null
  end if
from (select ' ' || 'This is the time' as text from dual) t
cross join (select coalesce(:chr, ' ') as chr from dual) c;
```